# Where are the functions like println bound in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm learning scala, and I see many examples where `print` and `println` are used in classes. I noticed that `Console println "Hello"` will print, but `println "Hello"` won't, saying `expected but string literal found.`, however `println("Hello")` will work.

As I understand, everything is a function of an object/class in Scala, and in my first example I'm calling `println` on the `Console` object, but in the second scenario I need the parentheses, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`println("Hello")` means `Predef.println("Hello")`.

All members of `Predef` are imported by default.

In scala you could import members of object.

You could call method `println` like this: `Predef println "Hello"`. For method with a single parameter you could drop dot and parentheses. It's called an `operator notation`. But in this case you have to specify target object (`Predef`) and argument.

See also:

#### Predef

[The Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) **9.1 Compilation Units**:

> Implicitly imported into every compilation unit are, in that order :
>   the package `java.lang`, the package `scala`, and the object `scala.Predef`

[Programming in Scala, First Edition. 4.4 A Scala application](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/classes-and-objects.html#4.4):

> Scala implicitly imports members of packages `java.lang` and `scala`, as
>   well as the members of a singleton object named `Predef`, into every
>   Scala source file. `Predef`, which resides in package `scala`, contains
>   many useful methods. For example, when you say `println` in a Scala
>   source file, you're actually invoking `println` on `Predef`.
>   (`Predef.println` turns around and invokes `Console.println`, which does
>   the real work.) When you say `assert`, you're invoking `Predef.assert`.

#### Operator notation

[Programming in Scala, First Edition. 5.3 Operators are methods](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/basic-types-and-operations.html#5.3):

> Any method can be an operator
>
> In Scala operators are not special language syntax: any method can be
>   an operator. What makes a method an operator is how you use it. When
>   you write "`s.indexOf('o')`", `indexOf` is not an operator. But when you
>   write "`s indexOf 'o'`", `indexOf` is an operator, because you're using it
>   in operator notation.

Comment: Perfect answer. I didn't see anything like this mentioned in documentation that I looked over, is this mentioned somewhere?

Comment: It's in the [API documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Predef$).

Comment: @TheSageMage: references to documentation about `import Predef._` are added to answer. Is it what you are looking for?